# Flutter null safety problem is : The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'

Tags: flutter, dart, null

The problem is null safety and migration how to solve The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'

````
```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

 class UserModel {
  static const NUMBER = 'number';
  static const ID = 'id';

 late String _number;
 late String _id;

//getter

 String get number => _number;
 String get id => _id;

 UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
  _number = snapshot.data()![NUMBER];
  _id = snapshot.data()![ID];
 }
}
```
````

Comment: my dependencies :         firebase_auth: ^3.0.1
                                       cloud_firestore: ^2.4.0
                                       firebase_core: ^1.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is just to define the CollectionReference more explicitly like so:

```
 UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
  _number = snapshot.data()![NUMBER];
  _id = snapshot.data()![ID];
 }
}
```

you can read about this [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration/)

Comment: please make it fulfill, thank you dear sir

Comment: Ruchit, Mentor Teacher you're actually genus. Thank you. thanks a lot